# Only first message receiving Sockets( C++ - Server & python-client)

Tags: python, c++, json, serversocket

I'm trying to send data from Client side (python) to Server Side, I'm able to send my first string data and from the second string, it's not working.

Client Side(Python side):

```
 # TCP Client Code

host="192.168.45.155"            # Set the server address to variable host

port=8800               # Sets the variable port to 4446

from socket import *             # Imports socket module
import json

s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)      # Creates a socket



s.connect((host,port))          # Connect to server address
print "Successfully connected to the server and ready to send some data"

strike = json.dumps({"A":"STRIKE"})
s.send(strike)

strom = json.dumps({"A":"STROM"})
s.send(strom)

stab = json.dumps({"A":"STAB",B="1"})
s.send(stab)

msg=s.recv(1024)            # Receives data upto 1024 bytes and stores in variables msg

print "Message from server : " + msg

#s.close()                            # Closes the socket
# End of code
```

Server side (C++):

```
#include <jsoncpp/json/json.h>


using namespace std;
            Json::Value root;
            Json::Reader reader;
    bool a,b,c; 
    string i;
//Server side
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
bool Style1;
    //buffer to send and receive messages with
    char msg[1500];

    //setup a socket and connection tools
    sockaddr_in servAddr;
    memset((char*)&servAddr, 0,sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(8800);

    //open stream oriented socket with internet address
    //also keep track of the socket descriptor
    int serverSd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(serverSd < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Error establishing the server socket" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }


    //bind the socket to its local address
    int bindStatus = bind(serverSd, (struct sockaddr*) &servAddr, 
        sizeof(servAddr));
    if(bindStatus < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Error binding socket to local address" << endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    cout << "Waiting for a client to connect..." << endl;


    //listen for up to 5 requests at a time
    listen(serverSd, 5);


    //receive a request from client using accept
    //we need a new address to connect with the client
    sockaddr_in newSockAddr;
    socklen_t newSockAddrSize = sizeof(newSockAddr);


    //accept, create a new socket descriptor to 
    //handle the new connection with client
    int newSd = accept(serverSd, (sockaddr *)&newSockAddr, &newSockAddrSize);
    if(newSd < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Error accepting request from client!" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "Connected with client!" << endl;




        //receive a message from the client (listen)
        cout << "Awaiting client response..." << endl;
while(1){
        memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));//clear the buffer
        recv(newSd, (char*)&msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
        if(!strcmp(msg, "exit"))
        {
            cout << "Client has quit the session" << endl;

        }
        string str(msg);
        cout << "Client: " << msg << endl;
        cout << ">";
        cout <<msg<<endl;

        //Receiving the values and assigning to the variables

            string text = msg;


            bool parsingSuccessful = reader.parse( text, root );
            if ( !parsingSuccessful )
                    {
                        cout << "Error parsing the string" << endl;
                    }


        if(root["A"]=="STRIKE"){
            printf("STRIKE CODE HERE \n\n\n\n\n\n");
        }

        else if(root["A"]=="STROM"){
            printf("STROM CODE HERE \n\n\n\n\n\n");
        }

        else if(root["A"]=="STAB"){
            printf("STAB CODE HERE \n\n\n\n\n\n");


            i = root["B"].toStyledString();
            string::size_type sz;
            int a = stoi(i,&sz);
            if(a==1){
                printf("Almost over, STABBED ONCE \n");
            }

        }
        else{
            printf("Wrong data sent \n");
        }

        string data = "Instructions Received \n";
        memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg)); //clear the buffer
        strcpy(msg, data.c_str());
        if(data == "exit")
        {
            //send to the client that server has closed the connection
            send(newSd, (char*)&msg, strlen(msg), 0);

        }
        //send the message to client
        send(newSd, (char*)&msg, strlen(msg), 0);

    //we need to close the socket descriptors after we're all done


   /* close(newSd);
    close(serverSd);*/
  }
    cout << "Connection closed..." << endl;
    return 0;   

}
```

What can I change to make this code work and receive all the strings?

How can I keep the server open all the time and send the messages from client whenever I wish and how can I store the messages sent from client in the server and execute them one by one?

Comment: Please try without having the server sending something back, maybe it is waiting for the client to receive the first response, and the client is waiting for the server to receive the second message.

Comment: The server might report that "Error parsing string" as all the three messages will be received as single string by the server from tcp buffer as client is sending without delay. So I guess you can modify the client to wait with s.recv() after ever s.send().